# How to open a menu with applications programmatically?

Tags: android, android-studio, menu

[image]I need to open a phone menu with applications programmatically. How can I do it?
I know how to open applications in the settings, but what I need is the application menu on the home screen.

Comment: There is no requirement for the launcher to have an application menu.

Comment: @CommonsWare I did not understand. I need to programmatically open a window with applications, which is located on the main screen of the phone.